# how to use the single input received multiple times in php

Tags: php

for example, I receive two inputs *value1* and *value2* and I want this input for different functions. Like addition, subtraction and multiplication.

my code

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['fnum'];
$y = $_POST['snum'];

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
  $sum = $x + $y;
  echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$sum'/>";
}
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
  $sub = $x - $y;
  echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$sub'/>";
}
if (isset($_POST['mul'])) {
  $mul = $x * $y;
  echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$mul'/>";
}

<body>
  <form method="post">
    Enter first number <input type="text" name="fnum" />
    <hr />
    Enter second number <input type="text" name="snum" />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="ADD" />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Subtract" />
    <input type="submit" name="mul" value="Multiply" />
  </form>
</body>
```

In this it is asking me to feed input for each operation separately

Comment: You can use session variable to store last input values and print them in the form as default values for fnum & snum

Comment: You can use GET method instead of POST

Comment: If you are asking for multiple input for multiple operations then use different input fields.

Comment: @Ainz how is that going to help??

Comment: It's not clear what the use case actually is. If you want to do all the operations simultaneously the replace the buttons with a set of checkboxes indicating which calculations you want to perform, and have a single submit button. Then adjust the PHP code so it does all the selected calculations and outputs all the results. But if you simply want the same values to show up again in the form before you submit it again, then just use PHP to echo them back into the inputs

Comment: @MuradHasan its one time input for multiple operations. But the user should choose the operation he needs. value of 100 and 50 if add button pressed output should be 150 after this i subtraction button pressed it should result as 50 without asking any other input

Comment: Another idea, why not just do all this with JavaScript? There's really no need for server-side code or postbacks or anything, just to make a simple calculator

Comment: Instead of `<input type="text" />` you could use `<input type="number" />`

Answer (score 2):

Good, Just use the posted value in your form input like -

```
Enter first number <input type="text" name="fnum" value="<?php echo @$_POST['fnum'];?>"/><hr/>
Enter second number <input type="text" name="snum"  value="<?php echo @$_POST['snum'];?>"/><hr/>
```

So that user don't need to put the same value again and when press the other buttons the form will automatically submit with the previous values.

**Note:** Remember, you need to check all the posted value is set or not and use proper conditions of POST method. Have a look at the given example of your problem as solution, I give it here to give you a proper guide.

Example:

```
<?php 
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = $_POST['fnum'];      
    $y = $_POST['snum'];
    $operator = "";
    if($_POST['submit'] == 'ADD') {
        $operator = "+";
    } elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'Subtract') {
        $operator = "-";
    } elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'Multiply') {
        $operator = "*";
    }
    $result = $x . $operator . $y;
}?>
```

Your form will be-

```
<form method="post">
    Enter first number <input type="text" name="fnum" value="<?php echo $x;?>"/><hr/>
    Enter second number <input type="text" name="snum" value="<?php echo $y;?>"/><hr/>              
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="ADD"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subtract"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Multiply"/>
 </form>
```

Result:

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo (isset($result) ? $result : "-";)?>'/>
```

Comment: Only thing I'd say is you need to check whether the $_POST value is set before trying to echo it, otherwise you'll get a warning when the page first loads, about the value not existing.

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "fnum" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mytestbase\tesppage.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined array key "snum" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mytestbase\tesppage.php on line 3

Comment: @zapperlu, have a look at the example, the complete code rebuild for your better understanding.

Comment: You sure _can_ use the @ operator but you should avoid it and instead write proper code (use `isset()` like you did further down in the other code snippets)